# How to make Qt Creator tell me about errors in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

Qt Creator didn't tell me about typo in my QML form - not even during runtime.. I'd expect this bug to be easily detectable..

```
anchors.bottom: parent.botttom
```

Is this just matter of settings or is QML just this bad? Instead of telling me that target of assignment doesn't exist, it just didn't do anything and anchor was not set.

Comment: @AlexanderV, don't provide links without explaining it. Actually your link does not provide any useful information related to this question.

Comment: I would create a bug report for it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that only available checks are outlined here: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-checking-code-syntax.html#javascript-and-qml-error-codes

It's static analysis (run by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+C) and it catches some of the problems.. Not this one though.